# jar file not finding main class

Tags: java, linux, jar

After compiling a java program with `javac`

```
$ javac -classpath javax.mail.jar:javax.activation.jar:. PriceEmailer.java
```

I am including the resultant class and the libraries I used into a jar, however, the jar file will not execute.

Running the java file on the command line works:

```
$ java -classpath javax.activation.jar:javax.mail.jar:. PriceEmailer 
Sending...
Email sent!
```

Now I want to make an executable `.jar` file. I placed the following in manifest.txt:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Main-Class: PriceEmailer
Class-Path: javax.activation.jar:javax.mail.jar:.
```

Creating the `.jar` file:

```
$ jar vcfm PriceEmailer.jar manifest.txt class/*
added manifest
adding: class/javax.activation.jar(in = 56290) (out= 50561)(deflated 10%)
adding: class/javax.mail.jar(in = 653275) (out= 617552)(deflated 5%)
adding: class/PriceEmailer.class(in = 4106) (out= 2205)(deflated 46%)
```

Running the `.jar` file:

```
$ java -jar PriceEmailer.jar 
Error: Could not find or load main class PriceEmailer
```

Why can't the jar file execute?

Note: The `main` function is in the file `PriceEmailer.java` which defines the `PriceEmailer` class.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
```

Comment: The entry point of a Jar file is normally set with the `Main-Class:` attribute.  I don't think `Class-Path:` works for this.  https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/appman.html

Comment: I included `Main-Class` in the manifest file pointing to the `PriceEmailer` class. Have I misunderstood the `Main-Class` attribute? Is it set incorrectly?

Comment: Is it correct?  There's no package for `PriceMailer` class?  I think you might have done something a little weird with the class path to get it to run on the command line.

Comment: Also: you can't add a Jar to a Jar file.  It won't work by default.  You need a special class loader to get that to work: http://one-jar.sourceforge.net/

Comment: @markspace You're wrong on all four counts. (1) He is specifying the main class in the manifest; (2) there is a Class-path entry in the manifest; (3) there is no package, as proven by his `java -classpath` command; and (4) he is not adding JARs to a JAR file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Class-path entries should be separated by spaces, not colons. See the [specification](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/specs/jar/jar.html#class-path-attribute).

Comment: Technically, that’s a tutorial;  the specification is at https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/specs/jar/jar.html#class-path-attribute.

Comment: @VGR Agree completely, fixing.